# Creating and saving a picture from data stored in std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qpainter, qimage

Is there a method in Qt with which one can easily create a picture based on data stored in a `std::vector`? I mean that in the vector there are colors for each `QPointF` points of a `QWidget` on which I'm painting with `QPainter`, but I don't only need to draw this picture on the `QWidget` using the colors in the vector, but to save it as a picture too.

Comment: What will be the dimensions of the image if you store its data in a vector?

Comment: @vahancho I store the color values in the vector consecutively, and I slice them up according to the dimensions. But if it is easier, I would create an other data structure with dimensions width*height and put the data in it. I just don't know what Qt method could be used for create and save a picture from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the initial dimensions of your image and have a vector with the color information, you can do the following:

```
// Image dimensions.
const int width = 2;
const int height = 2;
// Color information: red, green, blue, black pixels
unsigned int colorArray[width * height] =
                    {qRgb(255, 0, 0), qRgb(0, 255, 0), qRgb(0, 0, 255), qRgb(0, 0, 0)};
// Initialize the vector
std::vector<unsigned int> colors(colorArray, colorArray + width * height);

// Create new image with the same dimensions.
QImage img(width, height, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
// Set the pixel colors from the vector.
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        img.setPixel(row, col, colors[row * width + col]);
    }
}
// Save the resulting image.
img.save("test.png");
```

Comment: This feels a little "slow" is there no way to just vuild vector properly adn then pass it directly to QImage or QPixmap ?

Comment: @Dariusz, no you cannot create a `QImage` out of a vector directly. However you can do it from a raw data (array of `uchar`s) or `QByteArray`.